# Using SQL with IBM_DB connector in Python

Tags: python, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Has anyone used the `ibm_db` package with IBM's Python for PASE to update Db2 files on IBM i (formerly AS/400)?

I want to use Python scripts (from QSH) to update the Db2 database. My purpose is to populate values at runtime and update the fields of Db2 files. It works with static (hardcoded) values, but not dynamic ones.

Here is what I am trying, but it is not working:

```
import ibm_db

c1 = ibm_db.connect('*LOCAL','userid','password') 
sql = """INSERT INTO TEMPLIB.TEMPPF (TYPE, DRPARTY, CRPARTY, 
                                     AMOUNT,ACNUM, DESCRIPT) 
          VALUES('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'), 
          %(self.type, self.debitparty, self.creditparty, self.amount, 
            self.craccountnumber, self.description) with NC
      """

stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(c1, sql )
```

- `self.type`, `self.debitparty`, etc. are Python instance variables and have values.
- `TYPE`, `DRPARTY`, `CRPARTY`, etc. are fields of `TEMPPF`.

Something simpler like populating the 'sql' variable as below works:

```
sql = "select * from TEMPLIB.TEMPPF"
```

So somewhere I am not making the INSERT format correctly. Does anyone know the format please? I tried a couple of formats available on the Internet, but they are not compatible with Python, or they are not good examples.

Comment: Apologies. This was my first post and I think the font I used to copy paste from my word doc created this problem. Will take care. Thanks for showing interest. :)

Comment: Don't use `ibm_db` at all, just `ibm_db_dbi`. Then more-or-less just follow [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Answer (score 3):

First, your concatenation of strings with the modulus operator is not correct as `%(vars)` needs to reside outside the string intended to be formatted.

Second, you should be using SQL parameterization (an industry standard in *any* database, not just DB2) and not string interpolation of data and query statement. You can do so using the `ibm_db_dbi` module to pass parameters in the cursor `execute` call:

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi   # ADD DBI LAYER

db = ibm_db.connect('*LOCAL','userid','password') 

# ADD FOR PYTHON STANDARD DB-API PROPERTIES (I.E., CURSOR)
conn = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(db)   
cur = conn.cursor()

# PREPARED STATEMENT (WITH PLACEHOLDERS)
sql = """INSERT INTO TEMPLIB.TEMPPF (TYPE, DRPARTY, CRPARTY, 
                                     AMOUNT, ACNUM, DESCRIPT) 
          VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
          with NC
      """

# EXECUTE ACTION QUERY BINDING PARAMS
cur.execute(sql, (self.type, self.debitparty, self.creditparty, self.amount, 
                  self.craccountnumber, self.description)) 

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Hey @Parfait. That worked. Thank you so very much. tc :)

Comment: You have a typo (`exeucte`). Also, people normally don't import both `ibm_db` and `ibm_db_dbi`. Just use the latter, which has its own `connect()` function. It's typical not to give user and password, just `'*LOCAL'` by itself.

Comment: @JohnY ... Indeed thanks for that and I did not know `ibm_db_dbi` has its own `.connect()`. Let me test that and revise accordingly. IBM docs are limiting in this respect.

Comment: The official documentation for the whole ibm_db project is pretty bad, unfortunately. On top of everything else, OP is specifically using the ibm_db package bundled with [iSeriesPython](http://www.iseriespython.com/). So you can't fully rely on what you know about Python and ibm_db on mainstream platforms. Some things you just really have to test with iSeriesPython.

Comment: I should clarify that my previous comment incorrectly mentions iSeriesPython. OP was using the term "iSeriesPython" without realizing that it means something other than IBM's Python for PASE. The rest of my comment still stands.