# How to call an RPG program from Python

Tags: python, subprocess, ibm-midrange

How do you call an RPG program from IBM's Python for PASE?

I tried os.system, subprocess.popen/call but they didn't work.

*Update*

I found something on IBM's site. I tried the below; it does not give me any error but the RPG program does not execute (meaning it does not give expected result).

```
from itoolkit import * 
from itoolkit.lib.ilibcall import * 

itool = iToolKit()                                       
itransport = iLibCall()                                  
itool.add(iCmd('CALL', 'CALL TEMPLIB/TEMPPGM'))      
itool.call(itransport)
```

Comment: I can guess from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478410/using-sql-with-ibm-db-connector-in-python) that you are using iSeriesPython. However, you should be aware that this is not the only Python on IBM midrange. They are quite different, and you should be specifying which exact Python in the question.

Comment: @John Y, yes I am trying to use iSeriesPython only. And I want to call an RPG program from Python script.

Comment: For future readers of this question: OP is **not** using iSeriesPython. This question is about IBM's (5733-OPS) Python.

Comment: The code you posted in your question actually works for me (tested on PUB400.com). Are you sure that the RPG program is where you think it is, and that it is correct? Can you run the RPG program directly from a CL prompt?

Comment: Yes, the same code works. Actually there were some security issues which prevented the program call. It is working now.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for the XMLSERVICE-based Python itoolkit are [here](http://python-itoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest), specifically you want [iPgm](http://python-itoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#itoolkit.iPgm).

A simple example with no parameters would be:

```
from itoolkit import * 
from itoolkit.lib.ilibcall import *

itransport = iLibCall()
itool = iToolKit()

itool.add(iPgm('pgmcall','TEMPPGM', {'lib': 'TEMPLIB'}))
itool.call(itransport)

output = itool.dict_out('pgmcall')
if 'success' in output:
    print('Success!')
```

Another solution for specifying the library is to add an `iCmd` operation first, which adds `TEMPLIB` to the library list. You can find that and more examples here: http://python-itoolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in Python, but check out the [iPgm](http://yips.idevcloud.com/wiki/index.php/XMLSERVICE/Python#iPgm) on the Young i Professional site.

Comment: I tried itoolkit only as mentioned in the update section in my question, could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are using [iSeriesPython](http://www.iseriespython.com). It does *not* apply if you are using one of the Python distributions from IBM.

First of all, `os.system` should work. It just passes a command to the command line, so you can do

```
import os
os.system('CALL TEMPLIB/TEMPPGM')
```

And it should work.

But, just like any program you call on the command line, you can't receive parameters back that way. If you need to get the value of output parameters, use `os400.Program` to call any *PGM object.

The [documentation](http://www.iseriespython.com/app/ispMain.py/Start?job=Docs&testing=) isn't the most thorough or up-to-date, but it tells you what you need to know. In this case, since your example doesn't have parameters, I'm not including parameters in mine:

```
import os400
pgm = os400.Program('TEMPPGM', 'TEMPLIB', ())
pgm()
```

Normally you would want parameters, though. Here's the example from the documentation:

```
getprice = os400.Program('GETPRICE', '*LIBL', (('c', 10), ('d', 9, 0)))
getprice('PART_A', 0)
price = getprice[1]
```

Comment: John Y, now I understand what you meant by iSeriesPython. Sorry I am not using that and proabably can not as my company does not permit that. I am using Python 3.4 which is installed in my company's i-series. I tried os.system earlier as well however it gives me the below error. I am putting the call and error statement within second brace. 


{os.system('CALL TEMPLIB/TEMPPGM') 
sh: CALL: not found. 32512 }

Comment: I don't think you are understanding. You just left a ton of questions on the iSeriesPython forum, all of which are just copies of this question. But that forum is for the Python that you are **not using**. That Python is *very different* when it comes to interacting with native IBM i objects such as programs and database files.

Comment: I discussed this with Aaron Fransen through e-mail before posting the question there. I specifically mentioned that I am not using iSeriesPython. He advised me to still post the question, maybe some knowledgeable person can help. And about the series of questions, I tried to post the question multiple times there, but site was crashing. I informed Aaron about it; he then fixed it. But what happened was all my earlier tries came up as posts. I requested him again to delete all apart from one; he mentioned he will take care.

Answer (score 0):

The library XMLSERVICE has a set of demo programs in RPG that are callable and some sample code.  I just did a session on XMLSERVICE at the PowerUP18 conference and used this example, which does work in 7.2 and the OPS licensed program.

```
from itoolkit.lib.ilibcall import *
itransport = iLibCall()
from itoolkit import *
# XMLSERVICE/ZZCALL:
#     D  INCHARA        S              1a
#     D  INCHARB        S              1a
#     D  INDEC1         S              7p 4
#     D  INDEC2         S             12p 2
#     D  INDS1          DS
#     D   DSCHARA                      1a
#     D   DSCHARB                      1a
#     D   DSDEC1                       7p 4
#     D   DSDEC2                      12p 2
#      *+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#      * main(): Control flow
#      *+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
#     C     *Entry        PLIST
#     C                   PARM                    INCHARA
#     C                   PARM                    INCHARB
#     C                   PARM                    INDEC1
#     C                   PARM                    INDEC2
#     C                   PARM                    INDS1
itool = iToolKit()
itool.add(iCmd('chglibl', 'CHGLIBL LIBL(XMLSERVICE)'))
itool.add(
iPgm('zzcall','ZZCALL')
.addParm(iData('INCHARA','1a','a'))
.addParm(iData('INCHARB','1a','b'))
.addParm(iData('INDEC1','7p4','32.1234'))
.addParm(iData('INDEC2','12p2','33.33'))
.addParm(
 iDS('INDS1')
 .addData(iData('DSCHARA','1a','a'))
 .addData(iData('DSCHARB','1a','b'))
 .addData(iData('DSDEC1','7p4','32.1234'))
 .addData(iData('DSDEC2','12p2','33.33'))
 )
)

 # xmlservice
itool.call(itransport)

# output
chglibl = itool.dict_out('chglibl')
if 'success' in chglibl:
 print (chglibl['success'])
else:
  print (chglibl['error'])
exit()

zzcall = itool.dict_out('zzcall')
if 'success' in zzcall:
 print (zzcall['success'])
 print ("    INCHARA      : " + zzcall['INCHARA'])
 print ("    INCHARB      : " + zzcall['INCHARB'])
 print ("    INDEC1       : " + zzcall['INDEC1'])
 print ("    INDEC2       : " + zzcall['INDEC2'])
 print ("    INDS1.DSCHARA: " + zzcall['INDS1']['DSCHARA'])
 print ("    INDS1.DSCHARB: " + zzcall['INDS1']['DSCHARB'])
 print ("    INDS1.DSDEC1 : " + zzcall['INDS1']['DSDEC1'])
 print ("    INDS1.DSDEC2 : " + zzcall['INDS1']['DSDEC2'])
else:
 print (zzcall['error'])
exit()
```

Getting the library list and syntax correct is probably the hardest part